# Endurance workout with kettlebells

Tags: endurance, kettlebell

Is kettlebell swing an exercise that you can, with enough training to adapt, do for hours, just like you can row or swim for hours?

Is it a viable workout to keep up the form in the winter, or it will have a negative impact on the spine?

I know that working in the leaned position is bad for the spine, but it's the case when you're leaned for the whole time, for example farm working, while the kettlebells keep you in move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is kettlebell swing an exercise that you can, with enough training to adapt, do for hours, just like you can row or swim for hours?

Yes. Though obviously there's an individual upper limit on how heavy the Kettlebell could be, as their total power output (the amount of work put into each swing multiplied by the frequency with which they're performing the swings) would need to be within what their aerobic energy system can provide.

> Is it a viable workout to keep up the form in the winter, or it will have a negative impact on the spine?

Swinging a light kettlebell is a viable form of cardiovascular exercise, if that's what you're asking.

> I know that working in the leaned position is bad for the spine

That's actually very unlikely to be true. See:

Wai, E. K., Roffey, D. M., Bishop, P., Kwon, B. K., & Dagenais, S. (2010). Causal assessment of occupational lifting and low back pain: results of a systematic review. The Spine Journal, 10(6), 554–566. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.spinee.2010.03.033

Stacy A. Clemes, Cheryl O. Haslam, Roger A. Haslam, What constitutes effective manual handling training? A systematic review, Occupational Medicine, Volume 60, Issue 2, March 2010, Pages 101–107, https://doi.org/10.1093/occmed/kqp127

Comment: Kettlebell sport has 10-minute rounds and it's not unheard of for elite competitors to pass out. Granted, it's snatching or clean-and-jerking instead of swings, but who swings a kettlebell for hours?

Comment: @DaveLiepmann someone with very good grip endurance, a very light kettlebell, and no other options for cardio? 

Comment: @DavidScarlett My coach is a lady called Megan Kelly, who's the former female world record holder in the kettlebell swing (I believe it's total kg moved in an hour). She regularly swings for an hour at a time (sometimes over), but does it in sets, not continuously. No real reason for this other than I'm proud of her and wanted to boast a little ;)

Comment: @DarkHippo her feat is more endurance-swinging than i expected anyone to have done https://www.strongfirst.com/how-i-became-a-world-record-holder/ — but I'd still say that a world record attempt with breaks is not what the OP is looking for

Comment: @DarkHippo actually yes. Considering even after long training I'll be unlikely be able to keep up more than 50% of her tempo, the same effort with smaller kettlebell would make up at least 2 hours. Her body didn't collapsed, the only weak point was the skin on the hands (I know that from long distance running, only with feet).